# How to check float as hex value?

Tags: microcontroller, c, programming, microprocessor

I am reading 4 bytes from EEPROM to make a float value.

The specific eeprom I use(24Lxx Series) has 0xFF as default value.

So, if I read four bytes of 0xFF into float variable, it will have 0xFFFFFFFF

I want to be able to check above condition.

However, statement, if(floatVariable==0xFFFFFFFF){....} doesn't check out to be true, even if the floatVariable does have 0xFFFFFFFF inside(checked via debugger).

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Other than using a `union` or casting a pointer?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've considered using union, but making union for every single float variable would be make the code too messy. Thank you tho

Comment: There no need a volatile pointer or union! Just typecast `if ((uint32_t)floatVariable == (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF)`. And if it's too messy - create and use macros: `#define IS_WORD_EMPTY(A)  ((uint32_t)(A) == (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF)`. Withal you must be sure that float type (or any other you will test) really have size 4 bytes on your platform.

Comment: @imbearr Unfortunately, the cast of `floatvariable` to `(unit32_t)` will _not_ use the bit representation to do the conversion. The compiler will say "Ah! You're converting a `float` to a `unit32_t`? I can do that!" - and then go and do the _interpreted_ conversion that I warned about in my answer, and compare that to `~0u` which will NOT work.

Comment: @JohnBurger Yeah! You right! I have [test it](http://ideone.com/a7ePjq)... Now I will know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, when you're looking at the bit representation of data in memory, you only have two options:

1. Use a pointer to the variable, and "lie" as to what it is pointing to:

   > Note @erebos' and @Lundin's comments below: while you'll *often* see something like the following, it is NOT strictly conformant C. That "lie" could bite you...

   ```
   volatile float f;
   volatile uint32_t *p = (volatile uint32_t *)&f; // Take the address of f and cast it.
   ...
   if (*p!=0xFFFFFFFFu) {
       printf("%f", f);
   } // if
   ```
2. Use a `union` structure to change its interpretation depending on what field you acccess:

   ```
   typedef union FloatAs32 {
       volatile float f;
       volatile uint32_t i; // "Overlays" other fields in union
   } FloatAs32;

   FloatAs32 f;
   ...
   if (f.i!=0xFFFFFFFFu) { // Access 'i' field
       printf("%f", f.f);  // Access 'f' field
   } // if
   ```

I say "in general", because you may also have the opportunity to rely on the encoding of the float to get what you want. I'll need to check my references, but it *may* be that you can test for `NaN`, which is a special representation of floats to indicate (literally) "Not a Number" (such as `sqrt(-1);`)

Your test `if (f==0xFFFFFFFF)` tries to compare the *interpreted* value of the float against that number. You want to compare against the *uninterpreted* value.

#### Edit

I checked my sources, and I was right. If the "Exponent" field is all `1`s, and the "Mantissa" field is **not** all `0`s (which matches your case in general, but not specifically all `F`s), then the `float` is interpreted as a `NaN`. Note that the "Sign" bit is used to distinguish between a "Quiet" `NaN` (can be propagated through calculations) and a "Signalling" `NaN` (can cause exceptions). Luckily, a "Sign" bit of `1` (as in your case) is a `QNaN`.

That means that you can simply use the `isnan(f)` function and it will return true for your special case - and other cases too. Does your device produce a `NaN` at any time? Perhaps to indicate an error condition? If so, you shouldn't use this suggestion. If not... that's your call.

#### Edit #2

@dwelch made a good point in the comments about using `volatile`. The compiler *could* keep its values in registers rather than memory, so neither example above would have worked. Adding `volatile` tells the compiler to always read and write the values to memory rather than caching them. I've modified my examples to take this into account.

Comment: Yes. 0xFFFFFFFF in float reads as NaN. Is there any way to express NaN as literal?

Comment: The first method is commonly referred to as a "typecast"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923837/how-to-use-nan-and-inf-in-c

Comment: I'd use `isnan()` rather than comparing against a literal. If you tried to define a constant called `NAN` then did a `==` compare, it may still use the floating point library to compare interpretations rather than literal bit values.

Comment: Depending on the version and interpretation of the spec, you cannot use a union like this and guarantee that it will work.  You are supposed to use the same type going in as coming out, in as float, out as uint or in as uint and out is float is not the same type.  Saying that I have not seen it fail yet in practice.  Just be aware that it is possible that it wont.

Comment: For this specific case of reading from eeprom, you can "read" the eeprom using first a uint pointer (or some other favorite method of reading from a specific address) and check if it is all ones, then if not read it with a float.  If you are worried about this you dont have much choice, if you have a bank of floats you can scan through them quickly on boot using an unsigned int and not enter the normal code if any are all ones.  basically the pointer approach

Comment: @dwelch I agree that it isn't _enforced_ by the standard, but it is (probably) as a _consequence_ of it. From memory, the standard requires the union to use no more bytes than the size of the largest member - which implies that they occupy the same memory, which implies that the above works on 99.9…9% of architectures. I could envisage one where there was an extra (hidden) bit to flag that it was a `float` or an `int` and raising an exception on an illegal access... but who'd do that?

Comment: A compiler writer with an axe to grind. <grin>

Comment: Just pointing it out as a 1 out of a zillion chance.  bitfields fail very often and should never be used.  but this trick is used often and so far as I have heard has always worked.  Waiting for someone to post a failure someday if they find that one in a zillion compiler and/or platform.  I dont know if the spec covers optimization, if you come in as float and go out as float and you have an fpu you can use a floating point register and not touch memory, if you go in as unsigned and come out as unsigned you can use a gpr and not touch memory.  so maybe a volatile is required here for safety

Comment: @JohnBurger: `x == (some_nan)` won't compare `true` for any value of `x`, even the exact same bit pattern as `some_nan`.  A straightforward test for not-a-number that doesn't require any function calls is `if (x != x)`

Comment: @BenVoigt That's what I meant - but on re-reading I see I used the word "may". I should have been more definite with "would"! But I hadn't seen that "compare against itself" trick before - that looks weird! Is that defined to work only for NaNs? All special values (±∞)?

Comment: @John: Just NaN compare arreflexively.

Comment: Option one might actually violate the [strict aliasing rule of C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing). A pointer may only be cast to the original type or to a char/uint8_t pointer. A compiler could remove that code (maybe even if it's volatile) under the assumption that f and p may never point to or use the same address.

Comment: Indeed, please remove option 1 since it is a recommendation to use bad programming practice. Unions on the other hand, will ensure that there are no pointer aliasing bugs. Always assume that the code will get compiled with GCC and similar strictly conforming compilers.

Comment: @Lundin Note that option 2 is also (sadly) undefined behavior. As far as I know, the only way to win is good old memcpy().

Comment: @pipe: This question is tagged `c`, and I believe use of a union that way is legal in C.  In C++, it is undefined behavior to read from an inactive member of a union, just as you've said.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem is with the language in the C11 standard in section 6.5.16.1, paragraph 3: _"If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions **of a compatible type**; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."_ I haven't found an exception to this for a `union`.

Comment: @BenVoigt There is an explanatory footnote in another section of the standard claiming that it is ok, and that you will get the same bit pattern, but the standard itself does not say so. Hopefully it will be explicit in C2x. :)

Comment: @pipe You are confusing things, I don't see how the cited part is relevant: it is regarding _assignment_ and addresses cases such as `*ptr = *ptr;` (which can't be solved by memcpy). If you are referring to the union members, the relevant part of the standard is 6.5.2.3/3 _"A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier designates a member of
a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member,95) and is an lvalue if
the first expression is an lvalue."_

Comment: Where non-normative foot note 95 explains: "_If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
punning’’). This might be a trap representation."_ C and C++ are indeed different here.

Comment: @pipe 2) above is not UB because of strict aliasing either. See 6.5/7 _"An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:" /--/ "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)"_.

Comment: @Lundin I _did_ apply 6.5.16.1 way out of context, thanks. I still don't think 6.2.6 give any assurances that accessing one member of a union after writing to another member should enable "type punning" as explained. This type of language-lawyering doesn't belong in comments though, and I completely agree that accessing them through a union is by far the most reasonable way to solve the problem, the one that A) At least follows the _spirit_ of the standard even if one could argue about how explicit it is, and B) Is most likely to work without any surprises.

Comment: @pipe 6.2.6.1 §7 and §8 gives such assurances. It says that what value another type of the union gets is merely unspecified behavior, but it is guaranteed not to be a trap representation. As in, it could yield any kind of value and the compiler doesn't need to document which one, but there will not be a program crash/undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

super quick test based on my comments to selected answer.  Compiler did what we wanted/desired:

```
void fdummy ( float );
void dummy ( unsigned int );

union
{
    unsigned int ui;
    float f;
} myun;

void fun ( unsigned int a, float b )
{
    myun.f = b;
    fdummy(myun.f);
    myun.ui = a;
    dummy(myun.ui);
    fdummy(myun.f);
}



00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4070    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   4:   e1a05000    mov r5, r0
   8:   e59f401c    ldr r4, [pc, #28]   ; 2c <fun+0x2c>
   c:   ed840a00    vstr    s0, [r4]
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fdummy>
  14:   e1a00005    mov r0, r5
  18:   e5845000    str r5, [r4]
  1c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <dummy>
  20:   ed940a00    vldr    s0, [r4]
  24:   e8bd4070    pop {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  28:   eafffffe    b   0 <fdummy>
  2c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

Okay this got it to optimize to registers and it still worked as desired.  It copies the unsigned to

```
void fdummy ( float );
void dummy ( unsigned int );
void fun ( unsigned int a, float b )
{
union
{
    unsigned int ui;
    float f;
} myun;

    myun.f = b;
    fdummy(myun.f);
    myun.ui = a;
    dummy(myun.ui);
    fdummy(myun.f);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
   8:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fdummy>
   c:   e1a00004    mov r0, r4
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <dummy>
  14:   ee004a10    vmov    s0, r4
  18:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  1c:   eafffffe    b   0 <fdummy>
```

One or two examples does not a proof make, but the compiler writers wanted this to work even if ram is not used and the goesinta and goesouta of the union dont match.